# Implementing Leaflet plugin "Leaflet.Control.Layers.Tree" in R leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, javascript, leaflet-plugins, layer-control

I want to use "Leaflet.Control.Layers.Tree" in my R script. I am using the leaflet R-package to draw my map. I found this great leaflet plugin: ["Leaflet.Control.Layers.Tree"](https://github.com/jjimenezshaw/Leaflet.Control.Layers.Tree).

How do I implement this plugin into a R script?

I tried to use this [explanation](https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/c084a59717f18e947a17955007dc5f92), to add a leaflet plugin in R.

Could someone provide me a working example? This is my code now:

```
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)

layerTreePlugin <- htmlDependency(name = "Leaflet.Control.Layers.Tree"
                                  ,version = "1.0.2"
                                  ,src = c(href = "./www/js/")
                                  ,script = "L.Control.Layers.Tree.js"
                                  ,stylesheet = "L.Control.Layers.Tree.css"
)
registerPlugin <- function(map,plugin) {
  map$dependencies <- c(map$dependencies,list(plugin))
  map
}
# Draw the Leaflet map
leaflet() %>%
  # Base groups
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap,group = "osm"
                   ,options = tileOptions(maxZoom = 25,maxNativeZoom = 19)) %>%
  # Plugin
  registerPlugin(layerTreePlugin) %>%
  onRender("function(el,x) {
      var baseTree = new L.control.layers.tree({
      label: 'Base Layers',
      children: [
         {
             label: 'World &#x1f5fa;',
             children: [
                 { label: 'OpenStreetMap', layer: osm },
                 { label: 'Esri', layer: esri },
                 { label: 'Google Satellite', layer: g_s },
             ]
         },
         {
             label: 'Europe',
             children: [
                 { label: 'France', layer: france },
                 { label: 'Germany', layer: germany },
                 { label: 'Spain', layer: spain },
             ]
         },
      ]
      });
      baseTree.addTo(this);}"
  )
```